# Applying jQuery methods on DOM elements

Tags: jquery, dom

i started learning jQuery and i wish to know why jquery methods cannot be applied

in this example :

```
$('p')[0].html('salut !'); //for this instruction i got this error :
                           //"TypeError: $(...)[0].html is not a function "
```

while this one works :

```
$('body')[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
```

i m confused and i wish to know what is the difference between these 2 cases.

here is another example for the same problem :

```
var listItems = $( 'li' );
var rawListItem = listItems[0]; // or listItems.get( 0 )
var html = rawListItem.html();
// Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'html'
```

here is the way on how to use jquery methods by using the .eq() :

```
var listItems = $( 'li' );
var secondListItem = listItems.eq( 1 );
secondListItem.remove();
```

thanks for supplying some explanation for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jQuery object is completely different to a `DOMElement`.

- jQuery objects let you perform jQuery operations of them. `html()`, `val()`, `eq()`, etc.
- `DOMElement`'s... don't. As they're `DOMElement`s, not jQuery objects.

If you check the [documentation for `.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get), you'll see you get a `DOMElement` back, not a jQuery object. The same goes for `[0]` etc.

[`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq), however, returns a jQuery object which lets you do jQuery operations on them.

`tagName` is a `DOMElement` attribute, which is why can perform it on the `DOMElement`s returned by `get()`, but can't perform it on the jQuery objects returned by `eq()`. The opposite applies for `html()` when used on `get()` and `eq()`.

You can, of course, wrap any `DOMElement` in a jQuery object via `$()`, which'll let you perform jQuery operations on it;

```
$($('p')[0]).html('salut !');
```

But in your situations, you should be using `eq()`:

```
$('p').eq(0).html('salut !');
```

Answer (score 2):

It seams that you're learning by practicing, witch is a good thing, so here's some pointer:

- jQuery uses objects, and when you wrap them into `$(...)` you will get an object
- when you use an array pointer, like `$('p')[0]` you will always get what the native array outputs, witch is a string, and therefor, not an object

in order to retrieve the first element as an object, you have **3 choices**

```
var jQueryObj = $('p:first'); // using :first
```

or

```
var jQueryObj = $("p").eq(0); // using eq()
```

or

```
var jQueryObj = $( $('p')[0] ); // wrap it in a jQuery call
```

and keep in mind, the **`console`** is always your best friend when testing javascript

[image]

Comment: Thank you for yours answers Matt and balexandre. This leads me to the root of my confusion's cause which is the fact that the $() returns a jQuery object when appended with a .eq() and a DOMElement when the array notation pointer is used "[0]" or the "get()" which makes me wonder about the nature/structure of the $() itself..

Comment: well, i got an answer here http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery : the jQuery is actually a collection of Document Object Model (DOM) elements. The eq() method simply reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index. aLL is great now :)

Comment: `eq()` is the same as calling `index` of the array, but, it will return an object instead of a string